# Google Maps Marker Size

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to set the size of a custom map marker on Google Maps v3. I am using the code below to generate the map but not sure where the code `google.maps.Size(12,14))` should be placed?

```
function init(){
    var e= {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(xx.xxxxx,-x.xxxxx),
        zoom:16,
        zoomControl:true,
        zoomControlOptions:{
          style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT
        },
        disableDoubleClickZoom:true,
        mapTypeControl:true,
        mapTypeControlOptions:{
            style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
        },
        scaleControl:true,
        scrollwheel:true,
        panControl:true,
        streetViewControl:false,
        draggable:true,
        overviewMapControl:true,
        overviewMapControlOptions:{
            opened:false
        },
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var t=document.getElementById("google_map");
    var n=new google.maps.Map(t,e);
    var r=[
        ["undefined","undefined","undefined","undefined","",xx.xxxxx,-x.xxxxxx,"/images/marker.png"]
    ];
    for(i=0;i<r.length;i++){
        if(r[i][7]=="undefined"){
            markericon=""
        }else{
            markericon=r[i][7]
        }
        marker=new google.maps.Marker({
            icon:markericon,
            position:new google.maps.LatLng(r[i][5],r[i][6]),
            map:n
        })
     }
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,"load",init);
  var map
```

Comment: Please format your code, and refer `Complex icons` [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex). it tells that put `google.maps.Size(12,14))` in `var image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the size of a marker icon, use the [google.maps.Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) anonymous object definition:

> google.maps.Icon object specification
>
> Properties
>
> Properties    Type    Description
>
> size  Size    The display size of the sprite or image. When using sprites, you 
>   must specify the sprite size. If the size is not provided, it will be set when 
>   the image loads.
>
> url   string  The URL of the image or sprite sheet.

```
if(r[i][7]=="undefined"){
    markericon=""; // default icon
}else{
    markericon= {
      url: r[i][7],
      size: new google.maps.Size(12,14)
    }
}
```